# Nuxt: Setting Axios BaseURL in .ENV not working?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, dotenv

I'm having an issue setting the `$axios` base URL for my api endpoint within my Nuxt app.

I'm using the dotENV module and I have this setting in it:

`BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/api2`

In my `nuxt.config.js` file I have:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
},
```

This doesn't work for whatever reason.  If I hardcode it and try:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api2',
},
```

it works fine.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Adding `require('dotenv').config()` to the top of my `nuxt.config.js` file seemed to do the trick.  Just like me to figure it out right after posting my question on here. Sorry.

Comment: I am in a situation that regardless of what I try, it doesn't work :(